# What should I do for identity connection between layers in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to consider some identity connections between layers in CNN and send input to the next layers. I used the code below for this and just concatenated the input with the other layer output and send to next layer, but I am not sure if it is true or not because the output of layer is different from what I expected. Did I use a true way for sending input to other layers and identity connections like ResNet?

```
wtm=Input((4,4,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv1)
convaux1=Concatenate(axis=3)([conv2,image])
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convaux1)
BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I')(BN)

#-----------------------adding w---------------------------------------
wpad=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda xy: xy[0] + Kr.backend.spatial_2d_padding(xy[1], padding=((0, 24), (0, 24))))
encoded_merged=wpad([encoded,wtm])

#-----------------------decoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
deconv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(encoded_merged)
deconv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv1)
convaux2=Concatenate(axis=3)([deconv2,image])
BNda=BatchNormalization()(convaux2)
deconv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl3d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BNda)
deconv4 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl4d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv3)
BNd=BatchNormalization()(deconv4)

decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output')(BNd) 

model=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=decoded)
```

Comment: You need to be more precise, you say it is different from what you expected but you didn't state your expectation.

Comment: I say this because I think by doing this I should see better results in my implementations:) but I want to know this method I used here is true or not by concatenating I am worried about derivatives that calculated true or not? I use MNIST and before doing this I could see numbers in intermediate layer output but now it does not show precisely and I do not know it is due to using these connections or not?

Comment: Sorry, you are being too vague.

Comment: I want to know is it true to concatenate layers when I want to sent input to the next layers like ResNet?